# Support of random variable with value in $\mathbb{R}^+\cup \{+\infty\}$

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ a real random variable whose values are in $\mathbb{R}^+\cup \{+\infty\}$. For instance, we can think X as the first hit time of some process. It is usual to show that actually, $$\mathbb{P}(X<+\infty)=1, \quad \text{ie:} \quad \mathbb{P}(X=+\infty)=0.$$ 
My question is then : what is the support of $X$ ?

Comment: Have you thought through this question? Since $\infty$ is not in the support (and it's not a number anyway), what is?

Comment: My definition of support is the closure of all $x$ such that the density valued in $x$ is not $0$. But here, $X$ may not have density. So can you tell me why you reject $+\infty$ ? Sorry if it's dumb question.

Comment: Because you have already rejected it. You have your answer already, wherever the density is positive.